# Can I farm soul hearts from Larry Jr?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I've noticed that the poo piles left by Larry Jr (or the later stage unnamed twin worm-like things) can be broken for hearts and soul hearts. Is there a limit to how many drops can be made from Larry poo, or how many poo piles Larry can drop?

If not, one could potentially fill the health meter with soul hearts, right?

Comment: Not sure of any reason why it's not possible, but it'd take forever, surely? But remember, as soon as you kill him, all poop disappears, so make sure you don't accidentally decimate him while farming :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My original answer stated that this would not work, but I have discovered that is incorrect. Poo piles that Larry Jr drops will in fact drop items. So far I have only observed hearts and soul hearts, but I would assume that the drop rate is the same as that of any other poo piles. The piles will drop items if the player pops them or if Larry pops them.

It may be slightly impractical to farm items this way because if you shoot at the poo piles you risk hitting Larry and possibly killing him, and you have to get hit infrequently enough to make up lost health with item drops.

So, it seems that you are correct that you could eventually fill the heart meter with soul hearts, but it would probably take a very, very long time.

Comment: This sounds plausible but I'd like something definitive. Let me know if you end up testing your theory.

Comment: Poop farming is actually something I've done myself with profit. It's definitely possible and not particularly risky.

Comment: @badp It's probably just risky for me because I am bad at avoiding Larry.

Answer (score 0):

Right, but it will take a long time.

Comment: Can you prove your claim?

Comment: Can you prove I'm wrong? ;)

Comment: touché... the only thing provable without access to the source is a video showing items spawning from piles that were dropped by larry