# What kinds of things can be in poop and are the chances always the same?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

So far, I have only found hearts and coins in poop.  What else can be in there?  Does it depend on where I find the poop?

**Example:** Larry Jr. leaves a lot of poop in his fetid wake.  Do these poop piles have the same drop chance as poop piles found elsewhere?  If not, are there any other instances of increased/decreased poop productivity?

[image]

Comment: This question needs poop pictures.

Comment: I think this answer your question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34540/can-i-farm-soul-hearts-from-larry-jr

Comment: Free-hand poop circles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Binding of Isaac Wikia:](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Poop)

> Poop is a randomly generated item. The unlockable character ??? starts with an item that can generate poop. It randomly drops coins or hearts.

That said, I've made my way through the depths of Isaac's world more times than I care to count, and speaking from experience, have only ever seen Hearts (Regular *and* Soul), and Coins (pennies *and* nickels) drop from these piles of poo.

As for poop productivity, while I don't know the percentages, it doesn't *seem* like Larry Jr.'s poop has a higher chance of dropping anything. However it *is* a seemingly endless supply of poop. As long as you can stay alive, you can play in the poop all you want in hopes of farming some money or hearts.

One important thing to note, however, is the Lucky Foot. Unlocked by collecting 55 coins in one game, it will begin to appear randomly within the dungeon (treasure rooms, boss rooms, and Devil rooms). This little gem increases the likelihood of items dropping from those putrid little piles of poo.

Comment: This game disturbs me. It generates serious conversations about poop.

Comment: @Aceofgods poop is serious business, you try and see if you can succeed in laughing next time you are sitting on the throne.

Comment: @Aceofgods poop is the least messed up part of the game. I see you're new to Edmund McMillen's games